# firefox plugin to show cookies for a site

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies

In Firefox, I've been using [Cookie Monster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-monster/) for years to block/delete site cookies and third party cookies, in order to (partially) protect my privacy. But this is getting harder as sites require more and more cookies just to be usable.

I'm looking for a tool or plugin that tells me what cookies a site is trying to set, so I can accept/deny/mark-temporary cookies in Cookie Monster.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/cookie-manager/. This should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I'm still testing "Advanced Cookie Manager" to see if it does what I want.